# How do I get a dark shimmery bronze skin look for my glamour photography? (image provided)

Tags: fashion, retouching, skin-tones

I'm looking to find out how I can recreate similar shimmery/metallic skin tones such as with the first image provided.

I've searched over youtube and skillshare, but can't seem to find any tutorials or helpful videos close enough to this look. The closest I have found to be is by using a blue filter in photoshop with blending mode luminosity, though this leaves my images looking flat.

First image is the one I would like to achieve, second is my own.

Thank you.

[image: Desired outcome]

[image: My image]

Comment: It looks like the model in the top picture has naturally darkish brown skin.  Also contrasting it with the light-colored sand makes it look more dark.

Comment: Related: [How do you make a skin tone metallic brown?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61887/how-do-you-make-a-skin-tone-metallic-brown)

Comment: Related: [Glossy “metallic” looking skin](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72872/glossy-metallic-looking-skin/)

Comment: Related: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50918/things-to-consider-when-creating-realistic-highlights-and-dark-reflections-on-me On my answer I have two approaches. The second one can be useful on this case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a previous answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50918/things-to-consider-when-creating-realistic-highlights-and-dark-reflections-on-me

Here are some experiments. They are useful to help understand the nature of a glossy reflection  and some experimenting with skin color.

Obviously, the first step is masking the skin.

Now we need to use it to create two layers. Let's call the first one Tan and simply lower the curves. I did not force them because the image you posted is low quality.

[image]

The second layer, called Highlights needs to be desaturated.

[image]

And then change the blending mode to Screen and play with the curves. Flat to the left and sudently blow them. That is what a glossy reflection does.

[image]

This is a very primitive example but can give you the basis to play with the skin tones and reflections.

[image]

An important step is to think of your concept beforehand, that way you can use oil to prepare the highlights and probably make up the model in advance.

Answer (score -1):

They use Body Oil on her skin to make it shine.